# Loop does not operate as soon as app opens

Tags: ios, for-loop, swift

I have a loop that should be called when my app is opened or the main view is switched to. However I haven't been able to figure out how to get it to operate as soon as the app is opened. At the moment I have it in viewWillAppear which doesn't get called when the app is open, and the user has to switch to a different view and back to get it to update.

Here is my code:

```
    var paymentNum = 0
    var creditNum = 0
    for item in images {
        if item as NSObject == 0 {
            paymentNum++
        } else {
            creditNum++
        }
    }

    paymentCounter.text = String(paymentNum) + " Payments"
    creditCounter.text = String(creditNum) + " Credits"
```

I tried putting it in awakeFromNib but as expected, this just crashes the app.

Where can I put this code so that it is called as soon as the app opens?

Comment: By "as soon as the app opens", are you including if the user hits the Home button and then reopens your app, or when they switch from another app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` like this:

```
super.viewDidLoad()

var creditNum = 0
for item in images {
    if item as NSObject == 0 {
        paymentNum++
    } else {
        creditNum++
    }
}

paymentCounter.text = String(paymentNum) + " Payments"
creditCounter.text = String(creditNum) + " Credits"
```

}

Normally `viewDidLoad` or within a function that is called from within `viewDidLoad`.  But that is when you go t a new view.  Let's say you have a UITabBarController, when you move between tabs you will still be in the same instance of each view when you switch tabs.  If you need the code to execute every time the view is seen, then call your method in the `viewWillAppear` method.

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately... I do indeed need to have it execute each time the view appears, so it works fine when I switch between views. But when I open the app, it still doesn't execute.

Comment: post more of your code - your entire class - and I will give you working code.

Comment: The entire class? It's about 2,500 lines worth of code.

Comment: ok, alternatively, make a function and put your code iin it.  Then call it from a viewWillApppear method. override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

Comment: make sure whatever function controls the code execution is called in viewWillAppear

Comment: That still doesn't seem to solve it. I have two UIViews within the view controller. Will this make a difference?

Comment: no.  start adding println().  One before every other line in the viewWillAppear area. Make sure that function is being called.  If so, then the issue is somewhere in the logic execution of your code.

Comment: I've fixed it. I had to add `var array: NSArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("images")!` and then replaced `images` with `array` in the loop.

Comment: great!  Did the viewWillAppear part also help?